# large list initialisation failing silently

Tags: python

I am trying to initialise an arbitrary long list however the way I am doing it fails silently.
the code:

```
a_long_list = [True] * (1000000011)
```

I tried to try/catch exception without success. Ideally it would be good if the initialisation would succeed, but most important would be to detect if this fail or not.
Environment: I am using python 3.8.5 and  unfortunately numpy is not available on this environment
I also tried the arrays but without success (also failed silently).

```
a_long_list = array.array('b', (1,)*1000000011)
```

Comment: Do you need an existing object? If not then why not to give a try and go with generator?

Comment: Your `array` attempt failed because that tuple you used to initialize it requires only slightly less memory than the list in the original attempt.  Writing it as `array.array('b', itertools.repeat(1, 1000000011))` would minimize the memory usage during construction, but this is rather slow, and still likely to fail as this is a really big object you're trying to create.

Comment: What do you mean, it fails silently? You execute `longlist=[True]*1_000_000_000`, get no output, and then `longlist` is not defined? When I copy your first line into a python session on my machine, it works fine (but is a bit slow). The `array.array` attempt also just works, but is even slower.

Comment: @Oskar_U sounds like a good idea, but I I feel not for my purpose as I want to saved the  content and access them later without recomputing them.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks as you said it does succeed; I will try to push things further up to see if it gives an error of some kind when it fails.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch thank you, yeah that's the real issue I have with this. I was thinking to try on a bigger machine to confirm that more memory is solving the issue (which seems similar as the approach from jasonharper). On my env it does not go on the next line, no error, no core dump (although I would prefer python to raise an error rather than resort to the core dump) I am back to the prompt. I was hoping some outofmemory/malloc exception of some kind so that I could handle the situation.

Comment: @jasonharper: `itertools.repeat` would still require `array.array` to iterate element by element, repeatedly converting from Python level types to C, that's why it's so slow (it would also trigger overallocation, as it would be growing the array an element at a time, so capacity might be larger than used size). `array.array('b', (1,)) * 1000000011` is a much faster way to achieve the same result (and multiplication doesn't overallocate on the result; the final size is only a few dozen bytes larger than 1,000,000,011).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt to use `array.array` is first creating a `tuple` equivalent in memory usage to your `list`, so the peak memory usage is still too high. Multiply a short `array` made from a short `tuple`, not the `tuple`:

```
a_long_list = array.array('b', (1,)) * 1000000011
```

`array.array` will then efficiently produce the longer array, working entirely with the memory efficient C-level types (occupying only one byte per-element, not a pointer, typically 4-8 bytes, per element; more if you then started assigning values outside the range of the small `int` cache) with no huge temporaries you don't use.

Comment: Excellent! 
Although I am not sure why I didn't get a MemoryError Exception (or at least a stack trace) like it seems to be indicated here: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.MemoryError
Nevertheless your approach reduce memory dramatically mitigating the need for an exception.

Comment: @callmeSteve: There are some ways in which the process can believe it succeeded, but still die. The immediate one that comes to mind is the Linux Out-of-Memory Killer. The underlying `calloc` is granted by the OS, but you didn't actually have enough memory to hold it if you actually used it. When Python starts copying the pointer to `1` along the whole length, those pages are forced to become real, and eventually the OS realizes it overcommitted. At that point, the OOM killer is invoked, and it tends to target the process that is most egregiously overusing memory, killing it dead.

Comment: Python never actually knew there was a problem (`calloc` succeeded, so from its point of view, you had enough memory), so it couldn't raise a friendly Python exception. There's basically nothing a given user program can do about the OOM killer except not use too much memory and cross its fingers; configuring Linux overcommit is the prerogative of the sysadmin, and it's a global entity, not a per-process entity.

Comment: Thank you for the very informative answer, much appreciated.